# Send Opportunity records and related files to Google drive

Tags: rest-api, api, google-drive

I want to run a trigger that runs on after insert and after update on opportunity fetch the opportunities data and related files and send it to Google drive. Is it possible to do it via apex code?

Thanks

Comment: You can't implement FTP in Apex. Is FTP a specific requirement?

Comment: The client wants me to extract the salesforce data and put it to FTP site, from where they could pick up the data and consume it on their website. What are the other options where I could put the data if not FTP? Also, If not apex code, is there any other free tool that could help me in achieving this?

Comment: I shifted my focus from FTP to Google drive. Can I write apex code to send the data to Google drive?